# My Android app freezes when trying to open an AdMob Interstitial

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I am trying to show an Interstitial ad from AdMob in my app but it really doesn't work. In fact, I can see this message in Logcat :

> I/Ads﹕ Ad opening.

And then, my app is just freezing. Here is the code I have until now. **Note that I am trying to show this Interstitial ad from a fragment.**

In the method "onCreateView" of my fragment :

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(myContext);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(myContext.getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
requestNewInterstitial();
```

... and then, still in the same method :

```
send_love.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //new AttemptPostLove(user_id).execute();
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
});
```

And finally, the method "requestNewInterstitial();" from the Google Documentation :

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

**EDIT:** I've just noticed this "warning" in my Logcat :

> W/Ads﹕ It is not recommended to show an interstitial before onAdLoaded
>   completes.

Even if I don't fire the click event which should show the interstitial.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your app showing ANR dialog?

Comment: @3mpty : yes, after several seconds.

Comment: Your manifest would be like this: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#modify_the_manifest_file

Comment: @Santiago : Yes, my manifest already implements all of that. Everything is ok with banners, but interstitials don't show up.

Comment: @fraxool and is translucent? android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" a banner won't need this, but you need implement it for interstitial

Comment: @Santiago yes, I already use this theme. I've just edited my original post with a "warning" I get in my Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

IT's not direct resolution, but should help with typical ANR's problems:

[ANR WatchDog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog)

Setup, run it and it will crash application with elegant stacktrace in logcat, describing place that causes problem. I bet that there is some long running action in main thread...